# Mocking a function returned by a react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-testing-library

I'm building a pagination using the `useQuery` hook as part of the Apollo Client in React, which exposes a function called `fetchMore` seen here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/pagination/

Everything works fine, but I'm trying to write a test one of the use cases, which is when the `fetchMore` function fails due to a network error. The code in my component looks like this.

```html
const App = () => {
// Some other component logic
  const {loading, data, error, fetchMore} = useQuery(QUERY)
  
  const handleChange = () => {
    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        offset: data.feed.length
      },
      updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
        if (!fetchMoreResult) return prev;
        return Object.assign({}, prev, {
          feed: [...prev.feed, ...fetchMoreResult.feed]
        });
      }
    }).catch((e) => {
     // handle the error
    })
  }
}
```

Basically I want to test the case where the `fetchMore` function function throws an Error. I DON'T want to mock the entire useQuery though, just the fetchMore function. What would be the best way to mock just the `fetchMore` function in my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One way** to do it is to just mock the hook

In your spec file:

```
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks'

jest.mock('@apollo/react-hooks',() => ({
  __esModule:true
  useQuery:jest.fn()
});

console.log(useQuery) // mock function - do whatever you want!

/*
 e.g. useQuery.mockImplementation(() => ({
  data:...
  loading:...
  fetchMore:jest.fn(() => throw new Error('bad'))
});
*/
```

You could also mock the stuff that goes on "behind the scenes" to simulate a network error, do whatever you need to to test your catch.

EDIT:

1. Search for `__esModule: true` on [this page](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object) and you'll understand.
2. It's probably easier to just mock the whole function and return everything as mock data. But you can [unmock it](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestunmockmodulename) to use the real one so as not to conflict with other tests.

Comment: Hi Adam. Thanks for helping me out. I have 2 questions:


1. Do you mind going a bit more in depth on what the _EsModule: true is doing?


2. Is it possible (or realistic) moving ONLY the useFetch function, which is returned by the useQuery hook?

Comment: How is this the answer anyway to partially mock it? and just make fetchMore fail?